# react manage query string called data

Tags: reactjs

I don't know how to manage query string to react.

I made component class and it is composed of 3 other components.
It is not show data first time. Users have to select or click but
ton.

It is work well.

But I received a new feature. ;(

When users connect my site who copied url, the page has to show data immediately.

So I added query string. But I don't know when I call function.

I installed query-string.

I tried to use 'shouldComponentUpdate' function, but it was not work.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
 if (this.props.location.search.ids !== nextProps.location.search.ids) {

      // call some function....
    }  
    return true;
}
```

for example,
Users connect localhost:3000/my/home

It's ok.

But users connect localhost:3000/my/home?ids=1

It's not ok.

Summary.
I want to show data immediately when user connect to the site by query-string.

Comment: You are looking for react-router: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/

Answer (score 0):

to fetch data, the most common way to call api is calling in `componentDidMount`.
https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

if you are using `react-router` for your app, you can easily get query string with following feature of `react-router` .
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/query-parameters

and then pass query string to your api.

Comment: Thanks, I use componentDidMount function.

Answer (score 0):

I added componentDidMount and call myfunction.

```
  componentDidMount(){
    const query = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
    if(query.ids !== 'undefined'){
      let slice_ids = [];
      slice_ids = query.ids.split(',');
      if(slice_ids.length > 0){
        this.myfunction(1);
      }
    }
  }
```

Users can access the url.
Thanks @gnujoow